# How to add array of struct into dictionary,

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dictionary

I have created array of struct elements and have to add it into my dictionary.My code is given below:

```
 struct answerDetails
 {
    public string qId;
    public string question;
    public string answer;
    public string hint;
 }

private answerDetails[] answers;
private Dictionary<string, answerDetails[]> studList = new Dictionary<string, answerDetails[]>();   

foreach (var data in dynObj.Success)
{
    foreach (var student in data.Answers)
    {
        answers = new answerDetails[student.Ques_Ans.Count];

        int i = 0;
        foreach (var qInfo in student.Ques_Ans)
        {
            answers[i].qId = qInfo.qId;
            answers[i].question = qInfo.question;
            answers[i].answer = qInfo.answer;
            answers[i].hint = qInfo.hint;

            i++;                 
        }
        studList.Add(student.studentId,answers);//raising error...
    }
}
```

But when i adding the array of struct into my dictionary it generates `RuntimeBinderException`.

Comment: Any reason you are using arrays instead of `List<answerDetails>`? That should be easier to work with.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose using a struct instead of creating a class?

Comment: @ i have to handle more than one data types.so i choosed struct...i just given all types in string...But it will have some other type also...

Comment: Can you replace the `var` with the real types? The `RuntimeBinderException` is thrown because you use dynamic types, Are you sure it's thrown in the `studList.Add(...)` line?

Comment: Can you please provide the types of `dynObj` and `data`? Your code does not even compile.

Comment: @ actually dynObj is the result from deserializing json data...

Comment: @I just followed Kevin points.now it is working fine...instead of directly adding the studentId into my dictionary,i just stored the studentId into string afterthat i added the string into my dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a RuntimeBinderException at this line, your current dynamic student may not have any studentId property, or the property may not be visible